# Cant get While loop to work

Tags: c#

I am using a while loop to make it where if the user types anything other than "Yes" or "No" it will tell them to type something new in but everytime they type something else in it just spams "That is not an option" instead of starting back from the top. Can someone explain to me why? Thank you in advance.

```
              using System;

class CalculatorProgram
{
    //varibale for do-while loop
    private static string endAnswer;
    public static void Main() // <----- The Entry point
    {
     //Variables
     string Choice1;
    string mathChoice;
    decimal Num1;
    decimal Num2;
    decimal Answer;
    bool userWrong = true;

    Console.Write("Would you like to use Lane's Custom Calculator?(Yes/No): ");
    Choice1 = Console.ReadLine();

    while(userWrong)
    {
        if (Choice1 == "Yes")

        {
            do
            {
                Console.Write("Would you like to Add, Subtract, Multiply, or Divide? (Case Sensitive): ");
                mathChoice = Console.ReadLine();

                //User inputs the 2 numbers


                //Math Choices
                if (mathChoice == "Add")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("What 2 numbers would you like to use?");
                    Console.Write("Number 1 is: ");
                    Num1 = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.Write("Number 2 is: ");
                    Num2 = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    Answer = Num1 + Num2;
                    Console.WriteLine("Your expression is: " + Num1 + " + " + Num2 + " = " + Answer);
                }

                else if (mathChoice == "Subtract")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("What 2 numbers would you like to use?");
                    Console.Write("Number 1 is: ");
                    Num1 = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.Write("Number 2 is: ");
                    Num2 = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Answer = Num1 - Num2;
                    Console.WriteLine("Your expression is: " + Num1 + " - " + Num2 + " = " + Answer);
                }

                else if (mathChoice == "Multiply")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("What 2 numbers would you like to use?");
                    Console.Write("Number 1 is: ");
                    Num1 = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.Write("Number 2 is: ");
                    Num2 = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Answer = Num1 * Num2;
                    Console.WriteLine("Your expression is: " + Num1 + " X " + Num2 + " = " + Answer);
                }

                else if (mathChoice == "Divide")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("What 2 numbers would you like to use?");
                    Console.Write("Number 1 is: ");
                    Num1 = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    Console.Write("Number 2 is: ");
                    Num2 = decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    Answer = Num1 / Num2;
                    Console.WriteLine("Your expression is: " + Num1 + " / " + Num2 + " = " + Answer);
                }

                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("This is not an option! Shutting Down..");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                }


                //varibale for while loop to continue if selected Yes.
                Console.Write("Another Equation?: ");
                endAnswer = Console.ReadLine();



            } while (endAnswer == "Yes");


            //Goodbye Message
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you for using my program, goodbye ");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Environment.Exit(0);
            userWrong = false;
        }
        //If someone selects no for wanting to use my program.
        else if (Choice1 == "No")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you for using my program, goodbye ");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("That is not an option");
            Console.ReadLine();


        }

    } 





    }
}
```

Comment: You never read the users choice a second time, you do it outside of the while loop and then inside the loop you just print "this is not an option" and repeat.  Just update your code in the else block with the same line you have outside the while loop - `Choice1 = Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: BTW, welcome to SO.  It is great you are learning to program and I didn't want you to be discouraged about asking questions even though I have voted to close this question as being a result of a typographic error. As you learn to program, you will have many more questions and this is a great forum for getting those questions answered.  As another unrelated side note, you may want to look into using the [string.Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/858x0yyx(v=vs.110).aspx) method when comparing `strings`. It allows you to specify ordinal, case sensitive, culture, etc. when comparing.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program is waiting for the user to input a new answer after it prints out "That is not an option," you just never prompt them for it. You also never store `Choice1` again based on their new input, so it will always check the first `if` condition in your do-while loop with whatever they initially put in.

To fix it, change your `else` branch body to something like this.

```
//...
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("That is not an option");
    // reprompt the user so they know to type something in
    Console.Write("Would you like to use Lane's Custom Calculator?(Yes/No): ");
    // store the new choice to recheck next loop iteration
    Choice1 = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank You a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Probably your problem is that you don’t make a correct validation of the input.
Now, you read the input from console and compare with a static string so
“Add” is different from “add” and different from “Add(space)“.
I suggest you to make a more strong input validation:

```
Console.Write("Would you like to Add, Subtract, Multiply, or Divide? (Case Sensitive): ");
mathChoice = Console.ReadLine();
mathChoice = mathChoice.ToUpper().Trim();
//User inputs the 2 numbers

//Math Choices
if (mathChoice == "ADD")
{
     Console.WriteLine("What 2 numbers would you like to use?");
     ....
}
```

Comment: The validation is correct for `Case Sensitive` as the prompt suggests, to make it case insensitive it would be better to use the `string.Equals` override that accepts a comparison type, like `OrdinalIgnoreCase` or something of that nature.  The issue with the repeating loop though is not related to the validation for "Add" its in the else statement that is reading from the console but dumping the result on the floor and so the loop continues checking the same incorrect value rather than storing the newest one that was entered.

Comment: I know, I give a simple solution for a new user. If I implemented this function I will use enum.TryParse with flags. My answer is on the importance of correct input validation.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, I was explaining the reason for my downvote, you are not answering the actual problem. The problem was with not reading in input in the loop, not the validation for the user typing "Add", yet you state "Probably your problem is that you don't make a correct validation..."